# How do I marshall (in ideally in SWIG) a C# string[] to a C++ string*?

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, swig

I am new in C# programming and trying to call wrap functions that is in C++.

In C++ I have a function of the following prototype

```
string* swap(string* ptr1, string*ptr2){
    //swap the array of string
    return ptr2;
}
```

How do I wrap this function into C# (ideally using [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG), but not necessary)?

Comment: How is that array terminated? Can't you pass the size of the array?

Comment: What is the type of string? Is it std::string or some other struct/class or char array? Can you write more specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question for Java.

For Java, I did not find anything pre-packaged and trivial to use. I had to define my own typemaps.

In case you don't get any better answers for C#, you could start with the SWIG/C++ code described at [SWIG: How to wrap std::string& (std::string passed by reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753495/swig-how-to-wrap-stdstring-stdstring-passed-by-reference) .

You would need to replace references to Java types, JNI methods (those that include a reference to "jenv"), and "JavaThrowException."

These files from SWIG might also provide some relevant example code for C#:

- swig/Lib/csharp/std_string.i
- swig/Lib/csharp/typemaps.i

Comment: String is relatively simple(?) however I do not know how the string[] in c# is structure in memory. They are just continuous buffer with \0 terminators?

Comment: Since C# strings are reference types, I would guess that the array is an array of references to non-contiguous string objects. I don't know the easiest way to convert between C# and C++ strings in C++.