# How to pass strings to C++ function from Java using SWIG generated interface

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a bunch of C++ functions that take C std:string as function parameters.

I want to pass java Strings to those functions. I have generated a SWIG JNI interface between Java and C++. I can see the no-args constructor fine, but if I try to compile my java with the String arguments in the constructor, I get "cannot find symbol" and I think it is because of something funny going on with the way the class constructor was defined.

How do you remedy this problem? Is a typemap the answer? If so - where do you start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way, if you have a small set of functions to call, might be to simply wrap the C++ methods that take std::string with methods that take char* and call them from Java with Java Strings since the default type-map between Java String C++ char* will work as expected. You could also add something like this to your interface.i file:

```
%include "std_string.i" // for std::string type-maps
#include <string>
```

I think that this will work for your case without any modification.
For more information see [the Java SWIG default type-map documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_default_non_primitive_typemaps) and the
std_string.i and std_basic_string.i files found wherever your swig is installed. This
may not be available in older versions of SWIG (i am using 2.0.1).